# FIRStorageUploadTask putData doesn't complete when OffLine

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to handle what happens when the user tries to upload and image while the app is offline. Sometimes it works and firebase completes with a domain error and I'm able to create an upload task, however, recently the completion block is never called if the device is offline and I get a log message which is not in firebase documentation.

Here is the piece of code for uploading the image:

```
[self.storageRef child:imagePath] putData:imageData metadata:fileMeta
    completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * _Nullable metadata, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error uploading: %@", error);
            //create local task
            [self createUploadTaskForCurrentUserWithContentType:fileMeta.contentType filePath:imagePath isPhoto:NO];
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Project image upload successful");        
    }];
```

and here is the log message that I get **after** turning internet back online:

```
 2017-03-08 15:57:27.513 TEST[15661:822730] unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
{
  "name": "-KejhLQPdFBNfyWyqCfS/1489006585133.jpg",
  "bucket": "test-8822d.appspot.com",
  "generation": "1489006647755852",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "image/jpeg",
  "timeCreated": "2017-03-08T20:57:27.683Z",
  "updated": "2017-03-08T20:57:27.683Z",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "169509",
  "md5Hash": "5ZYpGG7d7jUthRIlM6yTAg==",
  "contentEncoding": "identity",
  "contentDisposition": "inline; filename*=utf-8''1489006585133.jpg",
  "crc32c": "4+FzAg==",
  "etag": "CMyIu4Lmx9ICEAE=",
  "downloadTokens": "570aa9ec-d97d-4e82-8feb-c8688f9d67c8"
}
```

Note:This is working fine while online, only problem is when I attempt to run the code while offline.

Comment: Did you solve this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Same here, solved?

Comment: It cannot complete - it has no way to continue networking past perhaps a 30 second window of extra time it can request when the app backgrounds. You need to detect going into the background, pause the task, then resume it when you go back into the foreground.